# Search duplicate on associate array through php

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing a program where my input is "palash".
Output will be:

```
p-1
a-2
l-1
s-1
h-1
```

My code is given below:

```
<?php

    $myString="palash";
    $j=strlen($myString);
    $narray = array();

    for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
        $val = 0;
        for($k=0;$k<$j;$k++){
            if($myString[$i]==$myString[$k]){
                $val++;

            }

        }
        $key = $myString[$i];

        $narray[$key] = $val;

    }
    foreach($narray as $key => $val){
        echo $key. "-". $val;
        echo"<br>";

    }


?>
```

But i want minimize my code and want to add a search option before 2nd loop to search whether the item is duplicate or not. So that i can eliminate my second foreach loop.

Comment: Check this :[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: I would create an array of int of size 26, then loop trought my string, using the ascii code to retrieve the correct index in my array and increment it. One loop. Then you retrieve the ascii code of the character to display using your index and display the value inside it :) Probably not the best, but i tought it would be nice to share

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_count_values` to count the values. You can check if there is duplicate when there are 2 or more values.

```
$myString = "palash";

$arr = str_split( $myString  );       //Split the string into array.
$arr = array_count_values( $arr );    //Count the array values.

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [p] => 1
    [a] => 2
    [l] => 1
    [s] => 1
    [h] => 1
)
```

Doc: [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if array key exists, then increment the counter

```
<?php
$myString="palash";
$j=strlen($myString);
$narray = array();

for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
    $key = $myString[$i];
    if(array_key_exists($key,$narray))
    {
         $narray[$key] = $narray[$key]+1;
    }
    else
    {
         $narray[$key] = 1;
    }
}
foreach($narray as $key => $val){
    echo $key. "-". $val;
    echo"<br>";

}
```

?>